# Not able to get first index from array in react native with slice

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, slice, react-native-flatlist

I have an array, In that, I have to show only first index of data.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];

var myBest = fruits.slice(-0, 0); (start index, end index)
```

But, Not able to get first index, Any suggestion?

And In flatlist, I have to render data from second index in some class.

```
Here is my code
render() {
    // const { profiledata } = this.props.profiledata;
     console.log('profiledata is', profiledata);
    return (
    <View >
            <FlatList
              style={styles}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator
              data={profiledata}
              extraData={this.props}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
          //code here for UI
               )
           }
         }
))
```

How to start loop in flatlist from second index instead of take seperate array from slice?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving slice the correct arguments.

```
var myBest = fruits.slice(0, 1); (start index, end index)
```

The `end index` is not included while returning the elements. Also `-0` doesn't make any sense

> **endIndex**
>
> `Optional.` The zero-based index before which to end extraction. The character at this index will not be included. If
>   endIndex is omitted, slice() extracts to the end of the string. If
>   negative, it is treated as strLength + endIndex where strLength is the
>   length of the string (for example, if endIndex is -3 it is treated as
>   strLength - 3).

If you want to modify the array so as to remove the first element, you can use `splice` or `shift` method

---

If you want to start rendering elements from second position in flatList, you could leverage the index property

```
<FlatList
      style={styles}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator
      data={profiledata}
      extraData={this.props}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
  //code here for UI
           if (index > 0) {
               // code for UI
           }
           return null;
      }}
 />
```

Comment: got it. Thank you, Any idea about How to start rendering data from 2nd index in flatlist?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: If I add if condition inside render method, its throwing errors.

Comment: Sorry for the error. I updated the answer. You need to have `{}` brackets instead of `()`

Answer (score 0):

The function your are looking for is [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

This function will allow you to take out the first item of your array, and use the rest in your component.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];

console.log('First : ', fruits.shift())

console.log('Others : ', fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `ES6 rest` operator to get an array without first element.

```js
const array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const [first, ...arrayWithoutFristElement] = array;

console.log('first element', first);

console.log('array without first element', arrayWithoutFristElement);
```

Learn here about [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)/[spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operators.